# Extract the type of the component props in react-storybook with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am working on a component in the story book and here is how it looks:

```
  import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
  import { ButtonProps } from './types';

  const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  // Destructre the needed props to be used across the component
  const { children, extraClasses, onClick } = props;
  // Memoize the onClick function so it is not recreated upon
  // each re-render
  const memoizedOnClick = useCallback(() => onClick?.(props), []);
  return (
    <button className={extraClasses} onClick={memoizedOnClick}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  children: <b>Test Button</b>
};

export default Button;
```

What I want now is extract the type of the props (ButtonProps) from the component itself so I can use it in another interface. I have tried the following line but it always says type is any:

```
type DefaultButtonProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Button>
```

Any help why the type DefaultButtonProps is always any while I declared it as following:

```
export interface ButtonProps extends HTMLButtonElement {
  children: ReactNode,
  extraClasses?: string;
  onClick?: (props: ButtonProps) => void
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your implementation of `DefaultButtonProps`, It was `ButtonProps`, not `any`.

Anyway, you can also test the following:

```
type DefaultButtonProps = Parameters<typeof Button>[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one worked for me. However, I still wonder why the first approach hasn't worked and always shows, "any" as type not ButtonProps. Do you have an idea?